# C# - Getting XML Child Nodes From SOAP (application/soap+xml)

Tags: c#, xml, soap

How do I obtain the SOAP child node values of username (Gusion)?
I am using C# in the backend.

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:api="http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body><api:some_api_call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<username xsi:type="xsd:string">Gusion</username>
</api:some_api_call>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried using this but it does not work

```cs
        public static string SoapNodeValue(string xmlString)
        {
            string soapString = xmlString;
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(soapString);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("api", "http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("encodingStyle", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

            return xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/soapenv:Envelope/soap‌​env:Body/api:some_api_call/username", nsmgr).InnerText;
        }
```

Comment: Give it a try first by following this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831910/how-to-extract-data-from-soap-response-in-c-sharp, if you still have issues, we can help.

Comment: I only want to extract a single node and I have tried the method above but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with your code, I saw VS throws this error,

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:
> ''/soapenv:Envelope/soap‌​env:Body/api:some_api_call/username' has an
> invalid token.'

For whatever reason, you have input the string with some unexpected encoding.

Now, copy and paste my string, and it should work,

```
 "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/api:some_api_call/username"
```

To prove my point, I created a python program,

```
import charade

def detect(s):
     
    try:
        # check it in the charade list
        if isinstance(s, str):
            return charade.detect(s.encode())
        # detecting the string
        else:
            return charade.detect(s)
     
    # in case of error
    # encode with 'utf -8' encoding
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return charade.detect(s.encode('utf-8'))
 
d1  = detect('/soapenv:Envelope/soap‌​env:Body/api:some_api_call/username')
print ("d1 is encoded as  : ", d1)
 
d2  = detect('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/api:some_api_call/username')
print ("d2 is encoded as  : ", d2)
```

And the result,

```
d1 is encoded as  :  {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.7525}
d2 is encoded as  :  {'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0}
```

Where d1 is the problem string.

I just love to dig it into more and finally found the culprit, there is an invisible [char](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2001C) U+200c in your string and it has a [meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A0%80%9C)!

[image]